# Stage file proxy and ImageCache oddity

Tags: media

Got some weird issues with [stage file proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/stage_file_proxy) and generating thumbnails:

1. When stage file proxy is enabled i can download all the files from remote server but i cannot generate any image styles.
2. When i disable stage file proxy i can generate image styles but no remote files are displaying (even though all of them should be downloaded in any case when the module is enabled, right?)

Just wondering if anyone has ideas as i'm going crazy with this, thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.  Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: We are having the same problem too

Comment: I see the same issue on a D6 site we are finally trying to redevelop. Was your issue on D6?